# To search entire file in a directory

Tags: linux, awk, grep

I have a list of some specific IDs in one file.

`file1`

```
10012074
10182922
10193829
10213367
10302542
10332316
10492906
10592572
10606805
10627446
10681600
10697905
10758584
10882944
10919833
10921530
11021848
```

And there are 30,000 files in this directory as `dir`. Preview of some files:

```
16320386  23505634  31404647  40262433  49727240  59977762  72739048
16321609  23507673  31409545  40263912  49731993  59983079  72743197
16321830  23508959  31410806  40274881  49733838  59991144  72743532
16323719  23513175  31413679  40277233  49737047  60000337  72743644
16324483  23513237  31415413  40280305  49739812  60006875  72746735
16325027  23514404  31421015  40283351  49741053  60017537  72748827
16326681  23516543  31422747  40288023  49752294  60022678  72751898
16327485  23517971  31427324  40290554  49752684  60023962  72752027
16333225  23518024  31427909  40291536  49755190  60025125  72754762
16334779  23520574  31428484  40291746  49756105  60029433  72755014
16336857  23522410  31430611  40293529  49756156  60034076  72757030
```

Bring those files from this directory that has the same name matched in the content of `file1`.

**Clarifications**: I want all related context of `file1` from directory containing 30,000 files and merging into a new file. *In other words*, I want to concatenate the files listed in the `file1` file fetching from `dir` into a single file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the 30000 files are located in `dir` which is a subdirectory of the current directory:

```
xargs -I XX cat dir/XX <file1 >result.txt
```

This will concatenate the files listed in `file1` and write the result to the file named `result.txt`.

`xargs` will read the names of the files from `file1` and will execute `cat` on each file.  The `-I XX` tells `xargs` to replace `XX` in the command `cat dir/XX` with the name of a file.

You may also use

```
cd dir
xargs cat <../file1 >../result.txt
```

which may be faster, but gives the same result. The difference is that instead of running `cat` once on each file individually, `cat` is invoked with as many filenames as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Input - file1
Output - file 2

Assuming directories containing IDs, are in same directory where file1 exists.

```
cat file1 | while read line ; do cat ./*/$line  >> file2.txt 2> /dev/null; done
```

Comment: sorry @Bharat it didn't help me and didn't give my desired result

Comment: Updated, initially yur question was not clear..

Comment: This solution works, but, according to the OP, there is only one directory `dir` containing all target files, not multiple directories.

Answer (score -1):

```
#Sorry for my english
#Maybe you need execute this script with "sudo"
#Keep attention in the urls, you must set properly the last '/' . Example: /search_directory/
#In my case I am testing in the same directory where i am executing the scripts, that is the
#reason why DirectoryWhereToSearch is empty and BackupDirectory doesn't contain any '/'

FileListName="filelist.txt"     #File which contain de list of IDs
DirectoryWhereToSearch=""           #Url of directory where search for files
BackupDirectory="./FoundedFiles"    #Url of directory where to copy the matches files
FileResume="Resume.txt"         #Contain a resume of the results
FileContainAllFiles="AllInOne.txt"  #This file contain the content of all the founded files.

if [ -f $FileResume ]; then
    rm -r $FileResume
fi

if [ -f $FileContainAllFiles ]; then
    rm -r $FileContainAllFiles
fi

touch $FileResume
touch $FileContainAllFiles 

if [ -d $BackupDirectory ]; then
    rm -rf $BackupDirectory
fi
mkdir $BackupDirectory

if [ -f $FileListName ]; then   #If the file which contain all the IDs exist

    #This while search for the files and copy all the match files.
    while read ID
    do
        echo "Searching for file with ID=$ID"
        search=$(find $DirectoryWhereToSearch -type f -iname "*$ID*")
        if [ "$search" == "" ]; then
            echo "File not founded: $ID"
            echo "File not founded: $ID" >> $FileResume
        else 
            echo "File Founded: $search"
            echo "File Founded: $search" >> $FileResume
            cp -rf $search $BackupDirectory 2>/dev/null
            cat $search >> $FileContainAllFiles
        fi
        echo "--------------------------------"
    done < $FileListName

else
    echo "IDs file does not founded"
fi
```

I didn´t understand very well which kind of results you need: just in case i copy all the contain of all the files in one file, and also i create a file where you can find a report of all the founded files.

Please, vote if it was helpfull ;)

Comment: Why do you use `$(rm ... )`?  `rm` (and `touch` etc.) does not produce output. Have you actually tried running this?

Comment: It is working perfectly...actually i have a doubt about when use $(...) and not...Anyway, i think after one hour doing this script and testing it, one negative vote looks for me a bit unpolite, despite my scripting level is not really good. I only tried to help

Comment: `$(...)` will expand to the output of the command inside. It's a command substitution. You are also missing double quotes around most of your variable expansions.  Run your script through [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/).

Comment: Is it now much better?

Comment: Yes, apart from missing double quotes around most variable expansions, and apart from the fact that we still don't know what the user wants to do.

Comment: I think my way of asking question is creating problem to understand thas why I edited my question

Comment: Why do you keep the negative score? Do you think my post wasn´t helpfull at all? Do you think I had bad intentions or bad manners, or it is because you are having a bad day? No idea why you discoureged people, even more when it is my first post

Comment: @JuanPedroMartinez I am really very thankful for your help.. At least you tried .. It's really appreciating

Comment: Thanks,@Bushra, anyway, i think you have to do only little modifications in my script to accomplish your task